# Simplifying this radical

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Sorry this is probably extremely easy but how do you simply the following radical?
$$\sqrt[3]{(x+y)^4}$$

Is it just $(x+y)\sqrt[3]{x+y}$?

Comment: It is just that.

Comment: Alternatively: $(x+y)^{4/3}$

Comment: Or $$x^{\frac{4}{3}} \sqrt[3]{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^4}$$

Comment: @MarkFischler That is not correct.  I think you mean $$x^{\frac{4}{3}} \sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^4}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt[3]{(x+y)^4}$$
Break $(x+y)^4$ into terms $(x+y)^3(x+y)$
$$=\sqrt[3]{(x+y)^3(x+y)}$$
$$=\sqrt[3]{(x+y)^3}\cdot\sqrt[3]{(x+y)}$$
$$=(x+y)\sqrt[3]{(x+y)}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\{\because \sqrt[3]{a^3}=a\}$$

Comment: $|x+y|\sqrt[3]{|x+y|}$ would be better.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt[3]{(x+y)^4}$ 
$=>(x+y)^{4/3}$;
$(x+y)^{4/3}$ $=>(x+y)^{1+1/3}$ ;
$(x+y)^{1+1/3}$ $=>(x+y)^{1}.(x+y)^{1/3}$ ;
$(x+y)^{1}.(x+y)^{1/3}$ $=>(x+y).\sqrt[3]{(x+y)}$ ;